# Compare one column data with another column data within same table in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
Id1      Id2
20441   20441
20441   26397
20441   37631
20441   82693
20441   1015597
37631   20441
37631   36551
37631   37631
```

I have data in a table as above, i would like to  mark as **IsDeleted** 
as 1 for the Id1 having value as 37631(if Id2 column value already exists in Id1 column then marke IsDeleted as 1).
[image]

basically i want output as below,

```
     Id1      Id2   IsDeleted
    20441   20441    0
    20441   26397    0
    20441   37631    0
    20441   82693    0
    20441   1015597  0
    37631   20441    1
    37631   36551    1
    37631   37631    1
```

How can i do that?
Here order of preference to mark as IsDeleted =1 is Id1 ascending order.

Comment: Why arent't the 20441 rows also marked as deleted? 20441 exists in the Id2 column.

Comment: I want to compare only Id2 to Id1, not Id1 to Id2

Comment: Your text is confusing. According to the red markings in your picture you mark the entries in Id1 as deleted, because the Id1 value (37631) also exists in the Id2 column. But the same is true for the 20441, so why are these not marked as deleted? What is the difference between the 20441 and the 37631 entries?

Answer (score 0):

Case should work for your requirement,unless i am missing some thing

```
select *,
case 
when exists(select 1 from table t2 where t1.id2=t2.id1)
 then 1 else 0  end 'Deleted'
from
table t1
order by id1
```

Your required output is also wrong( for example,1015597 not exists,so it will be zero)

Comment: No hardcodes please, what if i have thousands of records ?

Comment: I assumed only for one value,but this will work for all values

Comment: no it won't,,try now,i have modified it 13 mins back,may be you have taken old code

Comment: Id1      Id2    IsDeleted
    20441   20441    1
    20441   26397    0
    20441   37631    1
    20441   82693    0
    20441   1015597  0
    37631   20441    1
    37631   36551    0
    37631   37631    1

Comment: i am not getting required output , even for first and 3rd records IsDeleted is marked as 1

Comment: first and third exists in id1,so they are marked as deleted,is that not correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I don't understand problem. But why this variant doesn't suit you.

```
 UPDATE t1
  SET
    t1.IsDeleted  = 1
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table1 t2
  ON (t1.id1 = t2.id2 AND t1.IsDeleted  <> 1)
```

Or if you need select

```
 SELECT 
  t1.id1,
  t1.id2,
  CASE 
    WHEN t2.Id1 IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE 1
  END IsDeleted
FROM   
  Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
      ON (t1.id1 = t2.id2)
ORDER BY
  IsDeleted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT  t1.id ,t1.pid ,
    CASE WHEN EXISTS ( SELECT TOP 1 *
                       FROM     dbo.tbl AS t2
                       WHERE    t2.id < t1.id
                                AND t1.Id = t2.pid ) THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END AS IsDeleted
 FROM    dbo.tbl AS t1;
```